# JavaFX Preventing TableMenuButton from hiding all columns

Tags: java, menu, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I want to use Table Menu Button (`table.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);`) for hiding and showing specified columns in TableView. When I deselect all columns, [+] button hides, "No columns in table" pops in and user is unable to show any column.

I've tried to prevent hiding all columns by listening to `table.getVisibleLeafColumns()` and showing last hidden column, but then in ChoiceBox from Menu Button this column is unselected.

Comment: looks like a bug to me: the header should make a difference between no-columns-at-all and no-visible-columns-due-to-user-hiding. Curious: would you want to disable hiding the very last visible column or let the user hide it with the button still accessible?

Comment: Both cases for me would be suitable - just don't take away interaction from user. For now I do it with custom `ContextMenu` on `TableColumn` which is added to column header and disable deselection of last column. I think it (menu button) just shouldn't disappear when you deselect all columns. I know that i can add hyperlink or button to (table) placeholder which shows back all columns, but it isn't looking good and placeholder pops up also when there is no data in table.

Comment: hmm ... astonished that there is no column property isHideable (or I don't see it) - can you show your experimental code that's listening to visibleLeafColumns?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a bug (you might consider reporting it in fx' jira). The hack-around you mentioned in your question seems to work with a little trick borrowed from Swing: delay the reversion of visibility to some future:

```
ListChangeListener<? super TableColumn> visibleColumnsListener = c -> {
    while (c.next()) {
        // very last remove
        if (c.wasRemoved() && !c.wasReplaced()) {
            TableColumn column = c.getRemoved().get(0);
            // delay reverting visibility
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                column.setVisible(true);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

It may be dirtier than its analogue in Swing, though, execution of the runnable is at "some unspecified time in future" and doesn't state its relation to normal (originating from the ui) events.

Reported as [RT-38907](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38907) and just fixed (was duplicate: [RT-37616](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37616)), should bubble up in 8u40 ea in a week or two.